# Music Player with a smart Shuffle option

Tags: music-player, music

One of the feature that I love on Amaro (Linux) or Winamp (Windows) is the ability to shuffle the playlist, ie take all the songs in the playlist and shuffle them like a deck of playing cards. That way, when I play the list, the same song never repeat after the whole playlist have been played once.

In the basic music player on Android, and the few ones I've tried from the market, the behavior is the classical "Pick a random song" each time the previous one is ended, meaning sometimes the same song gets played 10 times in an hour, and others never get played.

Is there an app that provide this feature?

Comment: Since you mentioned Winamp - there is a version of [Winamp for Android](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp). Have you tried that? I am admittedly not sure of how exactly the shuffle feature works because I haven't used it yet.

Comment: It's the first thing I tried, as I was pretty confident to find this feature. But the shuffle in winamp for Android is just " play a random song each time" and not "shuffle the playlist then play it".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an App called "Just Playlists" that states the "none repeating shuffle" as one of its features:

http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/media_and_video/just-playlists_byqz.html

Comment: This is great, it's exactly the kind of feature I was looking for !

Comment: It's working great, I bought the paid version, only thing missing is a lock screen, but i'll write the developper about that

Answer (score -1):

Try checking this link out there are a list of media players that may work for you if you have not tried them already.

[Top 10 Media Players for Android Phones](http://compixels.com/499/top-10-free-media-players-for-android-phones)

Comment: Thanks for the link, unfortunately none of them has the feature i look for. But one of them let me edit Id3 tags, so i didn't completely waste my time trying them all

Answer (score -1):

Try [VLC player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc), It has a shuffle option that creates a shuffled list of your playlist.

Answer (score -2):

try TRMP Random Music PLayer. It has a great shuffle engine !

Comment: Can you provide a link to the app's website/download?

Comment: I tried it but got severall problems with it, the main one being that it doesn't allow custom playlist. My music is split in different style, classical and rock, and sometimes I want to listen to all my rock random, or all my classical random. TRMP only allow all my music random...